# How do I adjust this code to change title text on each powerpoint slide

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am trying to create an excel vba macro that loops through each slide in a presentation (the presentation was created with an excel vba macro) and adds specific text to the top of each slide.

Right now, this is what I have but it is throwing an error and I can figure out the set slide_title section and the with section. I think the for loop is correct, but not understanding the "with" section.  The "with" section text box characteristics are correct....but the code isn't executing because something is clearly wrong with it.

```
Sub update_slide_title_text()

    Dim ppt As PowerPoint.Application
    Set ppt = New PowerPoint.Application
    ppt.Visible = msoCTrue
    
    ppt.Presentations.Open ("C:\Users\Existing_Presentation.pptx")
    
    Dim ppres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Set ppres = ppt.ActivePresentation
    
    Dim pslide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim pshape As PowerPoint.Shape
    
    For Each pslide In ppres.Slides
        
        Dim slide_title As Object
            
        Set slide_title = pslide.Shapes.AddTextbox(1, 34.36292, -2.670787, 900, 90)
        With slide_title
            .Height = 54
            .Left = 34.36292
            .Top = 15
            .Width = 190
            .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "NEED TO CHANGE THIS TO DIFFERENT TEXT FOR EACH SLIDE"
            .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold = True
            .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 20
            .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color = RGB(0, 133, 85)
        End With
   
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: actually - I corrected that error and am still looking for a quick way to retain those characteristics in the with group but replace text across all slides....if the text differs from slide to slide, I guess no matter what, I'll need to explicitly enter it....for example, if slide 1, then text should say "XXXX". If slide 2, then text should say "YYYY", and if slide 3, text should say "ZZZZ", and so on...

Comment: If you know in advance what the text for each slide is, store it in a 1-based array ie Dim TitleTextStrings(1 to 42) as String then use .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = TitleTextStrings(pSlide.SlideIndex) to add the text